# На разных комьютерах один и тот же файл скачивается с BOM и без BOM

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, xml, кодировка

В django-приложении скачиваю с удаленного сервера XML-файл, чтобы распарсить его через BeautifulSoup. Обнаружил такую вещь - когда я запускаю тестовый сервер у себя на компьютере (Ubuntu 18.04), то файл скачивается с BOM. Когда то же самое работает на сервере (Ubuntu 16.04), то файл скачивается без BOM. И из-за этого код ломается:

```py
def get_data(self):
    r = requests.get(xml_url)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8' # или 'utf-8-sig' если есть BOM
    xml = r.text 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml-xml')
    return soup.find_all(self.arr_name)
```

Почему вообще так происходит?

Как лучше организовать проверку на наличие bom, чтобы сделать функцию работающей одновременно и с bom и без bom?

Comment: utf-8-sig вроде нормально работает даже при отсутствии bom

Comment: И что значит "код ломается"?

Comment: @andreymal 502 ошибка.  Меняешь кодировку на utf-8 и все становится ок. Но тогда все ломается на компе)

Comment: В питоне не бывает никаких 502, должно быть UnicodeDecodeError или что-то в таком духе, вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: @andreymal Может быть дело и не в бом, конечено. В логе nginx вот что: `*2150 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`

Comment: Ну так читайте логи этого самого upstream, а не логи nginx

Comment: @andreymal ну это uwsgi, у него какие-то неинтересные логи 
`DAMN ! worker 6 (pid: 26199) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn` Че произошло непонятно

Comment: Добавляйте принты в код, следите за воркером в диспетчере процессов и занимайтесь прочей отладкой чтобы понять что происходит

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее. В первой строчке, если BOM есть, то он будет проигнорирован:

```
u = r.decode("utf-8-sig")
r = u.encode("utf-8")
```

Если ошибка останется, значит она с BOM никак не связана.