# 502 ошибка сервера при создании объекта beautifulsoup

Tags: python, django, xml, beautiful-soup, lxml

В продолжение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1023779/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-bom-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-bom?noredirect=1#comment1740992_1023779) вопроса. Я просто неверно понимал суть проблемы.

Теперь я понял, что сервер выдает мне 502 ошибку при попытке создать объект beautifulsoup.

```py
def get_data(self):
    r = requests.get(xml_url)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
    xml = r.text 
    # До этого момента все работает
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml-xml')
    return soup.find_all(self.arr_name)
```

Похожий вопрос задавали [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235579/502-bad-gateway-using-beautiful-soup-python-django). Автор пишет, что ему помогла установка более старой версии bs, но вопрос аж 12 года.

И больше всего я не понимаю почему все начинает работать, если заменить в коде utf-8-sig на просто utf-8.

Если я правильно понял, нужно содержимое лога ошибок uwsgi? Или нет?

```
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55a594fefb00
dropping root privileges after plugin initialization
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 800448 bytes (781 KB) for 10 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x55a594fefb00 pid: 498 (default app)
dropping root privileges after application loading
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 498)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 30017, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 30018, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 30019, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 30020, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 30021, cores: 1)
Thu Sep 12 19:01:49 2019 - [emperor] vassal /home/mrnr/www/resttires/deployment/resttires_uwsgi.ini is ready to accept requests
spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 30022, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 30023, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 30024, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 9 (pid: 30025, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 10 (pid: 30026, cores: 1)
DAMN ! worker 9 (pid: 30025) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 9 (new pid: 30098)
```

Создал изолированный пример, в котором воспроизводится проблема (но только на сервере). [Ссылка на git](https://github.com/kkomissarov/bs-test)

Вот что происходит в терминале при запуске этого кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98599/discussion-on-question-by---502----).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была вызвана недостатком оперативной памяти сервера.